# Cookies not sent to tomcat server when ajax call is made from ember server

Tags: java, tomcat, ember.js, session-cookies, jsessionid

I have a ember server running on localhost port 4200 and a JAVA backend API server running on localhost port 8080. I use java's jSession for identifying user and for maintaining user sessions. cookies values are set as HTTP only from tomcat server.

Now when i make a AJAX call to Java server running on 8080 from ember running on 4200, cookies set by java session is not sent to the API server. How do i enable the ember to send java set cookies along with the AJAX calls?

Answer (score 0):

For your development environment either use: [`ember server --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080`](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli) or set cors flags in your java code such as [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers).

In production environment, instead of cors enablement, you can prefer to use a gateway such as nginx.

Comment: I tried starting ember server with proxy as Java server, cookies were not sent still.

Comment: how do your ajax requests go to the java side now? Do not send them directly to the tomcat, instead go to ember server. (change your host definition of ember application)

Comment: yes I do direct $.ajax call to tomcat. how do I change host definition?

Comment: if you are using $.ajax (and not using ember-data) just use the port of ember in your calls.

Comment: no. I don't use ember data. but my Java server runs on different port. s

Comment: ember server will make a proxy for that port. `--port` parameter will do it.